# save input() into the variable(python)

Tags: python, user-input

Here is my code:

```
def chose_range():
    while True:
        choice = int(input("Choose the range 100 or 1000:"))
        if choice == 100:
            n = 100
            break
        elif choice == 1000:
            n = 1000
            break
        else:
            print('Error, enter the right number')

        return n
```

I want to save result of this command into the variable.
How can I do this in python 3?

Comment: Are you asking "how do I call a function"? Try `some_variable = chose_range()`. Are you working with a tutorial? Just read ahead a little further and I'm sure it will cover this.

Comment: How does the result differ from your expectation?

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: @Kevin I am not so stupid:)Of course i tried some_variable = chose_range(), the problem was that I intented return too much.
I didn't catch this misprint.

Comment: What's the point of `n = 100` and `n = 1000`? You could simply `return choice`. However, your function will crash if the user enters a string that can't be converted to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Do not return within your while-loop you break (you have one indent to much).

```
def chose_range():
    while True:
        choice = int(input("Choose the range 100 or 1000:"))
        if choice == 100:
            n = 100
            break
        elif choice == 1000:
            n = 1000
            break
        else:
            print('Error, enter the right number')
    return n
x = chose_range()
```

Comment: Thank you!Didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like

```
res = chose_range()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "save the result of calling `chose_range()` into a variable (you didn't say which), then:

```
theVariable = chose_range()
```

However, note that your function does not always return a value to be saved; if it hits a `break` statement, it exits the loop without executing the `return` statement, at least in how your posted code is indented.